# Find Entity for field another entity

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity project and when I create new project I write skill and mainskill for this project in form. Then I have entity developer he have skill and mainskill too, early, when I create project, we find developer who have skill = 50% projectskill+project mainskill. Now this find still and I nedd addfind developer who have skill or mainskill = project mainskill 
This is I try:
But now I have error:

```
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

Whats wrong with createQueryBuilder????

```
            $query = $em->getRepository('ArtelCustomerBundle:Developers')->createQueryBuilder('d')
            ->where('(d.skills LIKE :skills OR d.main_skill LIKE :main_skill) AND d.unsubscribeDate <= :date')
            ->groupBy('d.email')
            //->where('d.active = 1 AND d.approved = 1 AND d.skills LIKE :skills AND d.unsubscribeDate <= :date')
            ->setParameter('main_skill', '%'.$skills.'%')
            ->setParameter('date', new \DateTime('now'));
```

I change

```
            $query = $em->getRepository('ArtelCustomerBundle:Developers')->createQueryBuilder('d')
            ->where('(d.skills LIKE :skills OR d.main_skill LIKE :skills) AND d.unsubscribeDate <= :date')
            ->groupBy('d.email')
            //->where('d.active = 1 AND d.approved = 1 AND d.skills LIKE :skills AND d.unsubscribeDate <= :date')
            ->setParameter('main_skill', '%'.$skills.'%')
            ->setParameter('date', new \DateTime('now'));
```

developer have field main_skill and I get mainskill for project (instring) and I want compare this filed: field developera(main_skill) and field project (mainskill = $skills = $project->getMainSkill();)

```
private function foundSubscribedDevelopersBySkills($project)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $developers = [];
    $emails = [];
    $skills = $project->getSkills();

    $skills [] = $project->getMainSkill();
    $main_skill = $project->getMainSkill();

    $except_emails = [];

    if ($this->notAcceptTags) {

        foreach ($this->notAcceptTags as $tag) {

            $q = $em->createQuery("SELECT n.email FROM ArtelCustomerBundle:Developers n WHERE n.tags LIKE :tag")->setParameter('tag', '%' . $tag . '%');

            $entities = $q->getArrayResult();

            foreach ($entities as $data)
                array_push($except_emails, $data['email']);

        }

    }

    $q = $em->createQuery("SELECT n.email FROM ArtelCustomerBundle:Developers n WHERE n.unsubscribeDate >= :date")->setParameter('date', new \DateTime('now'));

    $entities = $q->getArrayResult();

    foreach ($entities as $data)
        array_push($except_emails, $data['email']);

    foreach ($skills as $skill) {

        $query = $em->getRepository('ArtelCustomerBundle:Developers')->createQueryBuilder('d')
            ->where('(d.skills LIKE :skills OR d.main_skill LIKE :skills) AND d.unsubscribeDate <= :date')
            ->groupBy('d.email')
            //->where('d.active = 1 AND d.approved = 1 AND d.skills LIKE :skills AND d.unsubscribeDate <= :date')
            ->setParameter('skills', '%'.$skill.'%')
            ->setParameter('date', new \DateTime('now'));

        if ($except_emails)
            $query->andWhere($query->expr()->notIn('d.email', $except_emails));

        $developers_tmp = $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

        $developers = array_merge($developers, $developers_tmp);

    }

    foreach ($developers as $key => $developer_data) {

        if (isset($emails[$developer_data['email']]))
            unset($developers[$key]);
        else
            $emails[$developer_data['email']] = $developer_data['email'];

        $developerSkills = $developer_data['skills'];
        $developerSkills[] = $developer_data['main_skill'];

         if ($developer_data['tags'] && in_array('only main skill', $developer_data['tags']))
            $developerSkills = [$developer_data['main_skill']];
        $this->overlapSkills($skills, $developerSkills), $skills, $developerSkills);exit;
        if (!$this->overlapSkills($skills, $developerSkills))
            unset($developers[$key]);

    }

    return $developers;
}

private function foundSubscribedDevelopersByMainSkills($project)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $developers = [];
    $emails = [];



    $skills = $project->getMainSkill();

    $except_emails = [];

    if ($this->notAcceptTags) {

        foreach ($this->notAcceptTags as $tag) {

            $q = $em->createQuery("SELECT n.email FROM ArtelCustomerBundle:Developers n WHERE n.tags LIKE :tag")->setParameter('tag', '%' . $tag . '%');

            $entities = $q->getArrayResult();

            foreach ($entities as $data)
                array_push($except_emails, $data['email']);

        }

    }

    $q = $em->createQuery("SELECT n.email FROM ArtelCustomerBundle:Developers n WHERE n.unsubscribeDate >= :date")->setParameter('date', new \DateTime('now'));

    $entities = $q->getArrayResult();

    foreach ($entities as $data)
        array_push($except_emails, $data['email']);



        $query = $em->getRepository('ArtelCustomerBundle:Developers')->createQueryBuilder('d')
            ->where('(d.skills LIKE :skills OR d.main_skill LIKE :main_skill) AND d.unsubscribeDate <= :date')
            ->groupBy('d.email')
            //->where('d.active = 1 AND d.approved = 1 AND d.skills LIKE :skills AND d.unsubscribeDate <= :date')
            ->setParameter('main_skill', '%'.$skills.'%')
            ->setParameter('date', new \DateTime('now'));

        if ($except_emails)
            $query->andWhere($query->expr()->notIn('d.email', $except_emails));

        $developers_tmp = $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

        $developers = array_merge($developers, $developers_tmp);



    foreach ($developers as $key => $developer_data) {

        if (isset($emails[$developer_data['email']]))
            unset($developers[$key]);
        else
            $emails[$developer_data['email']] = $developer_data['email'];

        $developerSkills = $developer_data['skills'];
        $developerSkills[] = $developer_data['main_skill'];

        if ($developer_data['tags'] && in_array('only main skill', $developer_data['tags']))
            $developerSkills = [$developer_data['main_skill']];
        $this->overlapSkills($skills, $developerSkills), $skills, $developerSkills);exit;


    }

    return $developers;
}

private function sendEmailForDevelopers($project)
{

    $developers = $this->foundSubscribedDevelopersBySkills($project);

    $dispatcher = $this->get('hip_mandrill.dispatcher');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if (!empty($developers)) {

        foreach ($developers as $developer) {

            $message = new Message();

            if (!empty($developer[ 'unsubscribe_token' ])) {

                $token = $developer[ 'unsubscribe_token' ];

            } else {

                $token = sha1($developer[ 'email' ]);

                $developer_obj = $em->getRepository('ArtelCustomerBundle:Developers')->findOneById($developer[ 'id' ]);

                $developer_obj->setUnsubscribeToken($token);

                $em->persist($developer_obj);
                $em->flush();

            }

            $parameters = [
                'project' => $project,
                'token' => $token,
                'developer_name' => $developer[ 'firstName' ] 
            ];

            $message->setFromEmail($this->emailFrom)
                ->setFromName($this->emailAuthorName)
                ->addTo($developer['email'])
                ->setSubject($developer[ 'firstName' ].''.$this->emailSubject.' '.$project->getLevel().' '.$project->getMainSkill().' '.$project->getName())
                ->setHtml($this->get('twig')->render('ArtelSiteBundle:Mail:new_project_add.html.twig', $parameters));

            $result = $dispatcher->send($message);

        }

    }


}
```

help people

Comment: I don't see where you pass `:skills` parameter to the query

Comment: in function foundSubscribedDevelopersByMainSkills this `$skills = $project->getMainSkill();`

Comment: Vadim means, you have 3 parameters, `skills`, `main_skill` and `date`. You're not setting `skills`. So 3 params, 2 bound.